# How to lock/password-protect an XML file?

Tags: xml

I read and write data in an XML file. I do not want other people to read that file. So i want to create password for my file or lock the file.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you reading/writing the XML file using some program that you wrote or just using some text/XML editor?

Comment: If you can't put it on a memory stick and protect it that way, then I think you are going to find password protection won't help either - *how are you going to protect the password*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't password protect XML files without using encryption software. XML files are just text, but programs like PGP (Google away) should work well for strong encryption. 
Lots of Java-based encryption libraries available too, mostly open-source, just google them